# Every bounded operator is not compact operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was reading compact operator in a Hilbert space which is defined as 
"Let H be a Hilbert space over a field $K$, an operator A is said to be compact if for every bounded sequence $x_n$ in H, the sequence $A(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.
Then we have "Every compact operator is bounded but not conversely"
I am trying to construct an example for converse, one such example that I constructed is
$T \colon R\to R$ 
Let $x_n$=$\frac{1}{n}$ which is bounded in $R$ 
and let $T(x_n)$=$x_n \cdot n^2$

I need one more example in $l^2$ space.

Comment: An equivalent definition of a compact operator $A$ is that if $S$ is any bounded subset of $H$ then $\overline {A[S]}$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Try the identity map. All you need to do is find a bounded sequence in $\ell_2$ with no convergent subsequence.